# Pickups spawned using coroutines do not behave as they should

Tags: unity-game-engine

This simple game I created revolves around a player collecting different pickups to score points. I implemented coroutines on the pickup GameObject so they will spawn regularly every few seconds.

However, the pickups I created do not work after the second spawn onwards. This GameObject, called Jeans, is a pickup, and the player collects these pickups to score points.

However, the second and subsequent pickups spawned all ‘correspond’ to the first spawned pickup. Meaning, if there are 3 spawned instances of the GameObject, if I were to collect prefab 2 or 3, GameObject 1 will disappear and the score is added. However, future spawns of the game object cannot be collected. The player will just go through them.

These are the codes:

Consumable.cs

```cs
public class Consumable{
      
    // declare a variable of type 'items'
    // using autoproperties {get; private set;}
    // cannot be initialised in the beginning
        
    public items type{get; private set;}
    public float damage{get; private set;}
    public float health{get; private set;}
    
    // create the constructor
    public Consumable (items type, float damage, float health){
        this.type = type;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.health = health;
    }
}
```

Pants.cs

```cs
public class Pants : Consumable
{
    public int amount{get ; private set;}
    public GameObject [] pants;
    private int index = 0;
    
    public Pants(items type, int amount, float damage = 0, float health = 0) : base (type, damage, health){
        this.amount = amount;
        pants = new GameObject[amount];
        ItemManager.onHit += hit;
    }
    
    public void add(GameObject pant){
        if (index < amount){
            pant.GetComponent<BasicObjectScript>().index = index;
            pant.GetComponent<BasicObjectScript>().type = type;
            pants[index] = pant;
            index ++;
        }
    }
    public void hit(items type, int index){
        if (type == this.type){
            pants[index].SetActive(false);
            amount --;
        }
    }
}
```

ItemManager.cs

```cs
public class ItemManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Pants jeans;
    
    public GameObject JeansPrefab;
    
    void Start(){
    …
        jeans = new Pants(Consumable.items.JEANS, Random.Range(1, 1), 0 ,15);
        StartCoroutine(CreateObject());
    }
    
        …
    private void instantiateJeans(){
        jeans.add(Instantiate(JeansPrefab, new Vector2(Random.Range(-rangeX, rangeX), Random.Range(-rangeY, rangeY)), Quaternion.identity));
    }
    
    IEnumerator CreateObject(){
        while(true){ 
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(1f, 2f));
            instantiateJeans();
        }        
     }

    ...

public void consumablesHit(float speed, Consumable.items type, int index){
    Debug.Log("consumables Hit!" + " of type " + type.ToString());
    if (onHit != null){ //check if the event has any listeners
        onHit(type, index); //if yes, call them
    }
    // score update

    if (type == Consumable.items.JEANS){
        score += (int) jeans.health;           
    }
```

The BasicObjectScript that is calling the hit method:

```
public class BasicObjectScript : MonoBehaviour, BasicObjectInterface{
    public int index; 
    public Consumable.items type;
    public GameObject ItemManager;
  
    //this is the method that one has to implement (because of the adopted BasicObjectInterface)
    public void getHit(float speed){   
        ItemManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ItemManager");
        // call the ItemManager's consumables hit method, and the item manager will notify everybody
        ItemManager.GetComponent<ItemManager>().consumablesHit(speed, type, index);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Editing my answer for clearence.

I think you create a new array every time you create a new pant. Can you create your pants array at the ItemManager class and try to use that array?

Comment: I'm quite new to unity, so when you mean GetInstanceID, instead of having a private int index, i should create a unique id for each gameobject spawned?

For the second method of disabling the array, how do I actually do it? Do i just SetActive(False) the game object on the consumablesHit method? thank you!

Comment: I am not expert myself but I just try to find a shortcut for you. I'll edit my answer for cleaarence

Comment: I have seen your edits, i tried removing the GameObject array but it still does not work.

Comment: Then please try to pass gameobject to the hit method and try to disable that gameobject. Also can you share BasicObjectScript or whichever script is calling the hit method

Comment: I have added the basicobjectscript into the question. Thank you very much for your time.